# regular expressions: simplified form?

Tags: swift, regex

I'm finally learning swift.  The documentation that I've seen for regex in swift consist of something like the following:

```
let testString = "hat"
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: testString.utf16.count)
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[a-z]at")
let r = regex.firstMatch(in: testString, options: [], range: range) != nil
print("ns-based regex match?: ", r)
```

Is this the preferred/only way of doing this or is there an updated technique?
It's a bit verbose.

Comment: FWIW, if you do use `NSRegularExpression` (which we sometimes still use if we need some of the more complicated options), there is an initializer to create a `NSRange` without using the utf16 syntax: `let range = NSRange(testString.startIndex..., in: testString)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We’d often just use [`range(of:options:range:locale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/3126771-range) with a [`.regularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/compareoptions/1410450-regularexpression):

```
let testString = "foo hat"
if let range = testString.range(of: "[a-z]at", options: .regularExpression) {
    print(testString[range])
}
```

If you don't need some of the more advanced `NSRegularExpression` options, the above is bit simpler.

Comment: is this calling NSRE in the background?

Comment: Yes, the source at github/apple suggests it is doing precisely that.